# CSS not reflected in browser when running project

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Using Visual Studio 2017
I have a Single Solution with two projects.   I have linked the CSS files from project1 to project2, I can see that the css is being read correctly in Visual Studio Design BUT when I run the project it is not reflected in the browser.

Is there something else I should be considering within either project's settings?

I am fairly new to Visual Studio and was tasked to find a way to allow multiple projects to use the same CSS files.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you see the css file being referenced in the rendered DOM at all? Or is it there and being overridden or something? Would need more details to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see your styles, when you open dev tools in browser? If you don't you probably made mistake in linking css file. Try clicking on that link with SHIFT, if it directs you to your css file, it is right.
Otherwise try to find some typo in html classes or somtehing like that.
You can also try cache restart on that page by pressing CTRL + R

Answer (score -1):

To emphasize a bit what Chris W. said, what CSS query output do you get when you open the Network tab of your browser's devtools?

Comment: Hi, this is not an answer. If you wish to engage in conversation with the original post. Please use the comment feature.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).